# Function return to global

Tags: python, function

I have this piece of code:

```
def bricks(small,big,goal):

    current_lenght = 0
    current_value = 5
    number_of_bricks = big
    builder(current_lenght,current_value,number_of_bricks,goal)
    current_value = 1
    print("in bricks", current_lenght)
    number_of_bricks = small
    builder(current_lenght,current_value,number_of_bricks,goal)
    if current_lenght == goal:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def builder(current_lenght,current_value,number_of_bricks,goal):

    use_count = 1
    while (goal - current_lenght) >+ current_value and use_count <= number_of_bricks:
        current_lenght += current_value
        print("in while ",current_lenght)
    print(current_lenght)
    return current_lenght
```

and it doesn't use actuall current lenght from first use of builder, but it starts from 0 again. Why is it so?

Comment: Just by the way, but `>+ current_value` means "more than `current_value` with its sign unchanged," when you probably meant `>= current_value`. And it's "length," not "lenght." You might want to look over your code for typos first.

Comment: It's not recommended inside functions, but if you want to access a global variable define it at the top of the function as `global current_length` and then the function will look for the global variable and use that instead

Comment: `length` or `lenght`?

Answer (score 0):

`current_length` does not change outside `builder` function. But you return new value so just do this:

```
current_length = builder(current_lenght,current_value,number_of_bricks,goal)
```

first time you call `builder`

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is that you are not re-assigning `current_lenght` (sic) to the value returned by your function `builder` within the body of `bricks`.

I've fixed that and tidied up your code style a little bit to make the code a bit more readable. I am OCD that way, but good code style and commenting can really help with catching and fixing bugs too.

Hope this helps!

```
def bricks(small, big, goal):
    # Passing the following values:
    # current_length = 0
    # current_value = 5
    # number_of_bricks = big

    current_length = builder(0, 5, big, goal)

    print("in bricks", current_length)

    # Passing the following values:
    # current_length as calculated above
    # current_value = 1
    # number_of_bricks = small

    builder(current_length, 1, small, goal)

    if current_length == goal:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def builder(current_length, current_value, number_of_bricks, goal):

    use_count = 1

    while (goal - current_length) >+ current_value and use_count <= number_of_bricks:
        current_length += current_value
        print("in while", current_length)
    print(current_length)

    return current_length

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Let's test what we've written
    bricks(1, 10, 100)
```